# Force IE to Edge Mode rather than compatibility mode in SP2010

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, sharepoint-2010

I was having a terrible time forcing IE to render beyond IE8 mode in my dev environment. There were many posts that talked about IE and local 192.168.x.x ips. I created a local .net TLD that worked on my internal network but not while debugging on the dev server.

Simply adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

did not work. I made sure it was first, I changed !DOCTYPE to plain old:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I also tried adding the response header at the IIS level. No Love.

Also tried:

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    HtmlMeta MetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
    MetaTag.Attributes["http-equiv"] = "Content-Type";
    MetaTag.Attributes["content"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8;";
    Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, MetaTag);
    MetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
    MetaTag.Attributes["http-equiv"] = "X-UA-Compatible";
    MetaTag.Attributes["content"] = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, MetaTag);
}
```

Still no love...

Comment: Since this was such a pain I thought I would share Q&A style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the modern DOCTYPE. The one you have in your answer forces the rendering engine into a compatibility mode, not modern standards. Also if you can add the X-UA-Compatible value to a response header you are better off because IE does not have to change engines. But honestly if you use the modern DOCTYPE you should be fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I did try this. Without any love though. However, I don't recall that I reset the theme when I did this. I will have to experiment. It may be that the real secret is the theme dance.

Comment: Reset master pages to factory then changed the DOCTYPE and tested. In addition I did not change the html lang spec. This worked in testing IE on the server. Changes reflected in my post.

Comment: Yeah the DOCTYPE is not really required any longer. It is supported to help legacy browsers. The original DOCTYPE you had was telling the browser to use HTML4/CSS2 standards. It is one of the biggest reasons sites 'don't work' in IE 11. Basically you are saying I have not updated this page since before the mortgage crisis so treat me as if it is 2007.

Comment: Found my own post again. I still had to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> to get proper rendering in IE10 and IE11 on a local dev VM. But this IS the answer. Sorry it took me forever to get back here.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the v4 masterpage header to the following worked like a charm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

After making these changes and ensuring they were published as default. Bouncing IIS, SharePoint, and SQL for good measure... No Love!?!?

I had to change the theme in site settings to anything and change it back. Then all worked as expected.

Since this was such a pain I thought I would share. I have not tried this in SP2013 because everything seems to render ok there.

EDIT: Reset master pages to factory then changed the DOCTYPE and tested per Chris Love's suggestion. I also did not change the html lang spec from default. This worked in testing IE on the server. Changes reflected in this post.

Also, removed chrome=1 as it is [retiring.](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html)

I believe the secret sauce here is the proper DOCTYPE and the theme dance ***if*** the change does not take effect.